# Redux Middleware, Promise or Thunk

Tags: redux

I'm using Redux Thunk as middleware for Async call, but I have seen examples that use Redux Promise, what are the differences, between these middlewares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `redux-thunk` & `react-promise` delay dispatching at the suitable time .

However there are some points of difference :

### 1. When it intervenes :

- `react-thunk` intervenes when the action creator returns a function, not a literal object .
- `react-promise` intervenes when the action creator still returns an action (literal object ) but this action must have property `payload`, and the value of this `payload` is a promise (instance of `Promise`).

### 2. Who is the last dispatcher :

- `redux-thunk` : You are the last dispatcher, `reach-thunk` just gives you access to `dispatch` function as an argument of the function (that is returned by action creator)
- `redux-promise`: It will takes the promise (in the `payload` property) and dispatch the same action type in the `then` block , but it replaces the payload of the action with the response (the argument of then block ).

Comment: You are Welcome!